# Selenium Xpath how do i get the value of an html id tag using starts-with

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a html with a div tag which has an id attribute.  I would like to get the value of the id attribute using starts-with in Xpath.

Here is an HTML snippet:

```
<div id="operations_edit_process_list_task_3">
    <span/>
<span>
<span class=" myinlineblock" title="Clean"
      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;">
<select tabindex="-1">
</span>
</span>
```

Using Xpath starts with I would like to get the id value into a variable so i can use it later in my code.

The number 3 at the end is dynamic, if i can use starts-with then i can get the id value out.

I tried the following Xpath, it does not work:

```
//div[starts-with[@div="operations_edit_process_list_task"]]
```

What is the correct syntax?
Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it with `xpath`, but with `css_selector` you can do

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id^='operations_edit_process_list_task']")
id = element.get_attribute("id")
# do whatever you want with the id value
```

I think the correct syntax for `xpath` is

```
//*[starts-with(div, "operations_edit_process_list_task")]
```

Comment: Can i print out the value of the id variable to the console? I tried print id.text i get an error 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: I also tried print id.get_attribute("id") i get the error 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: @RiazLadhani `id` is string, it has the value of what `element.get_attribute("id")` returned.

Comment: Just do `print id`, you should get `"operations_edit_process_list_task_3"`

Answer (score 1):

To find an element with an XPath where the id starts with :

```
"//*[starts-with(@id,'beginning of id')]"
```

To find an element with a CSS selector where the id starts with :

```
"[id^='beginning of id']"
```